# What icons would be better to distinguish between knowing an answer or not?

Tags: website-design

I know the headline might not be that explanatory, so let me elaborate. I have a website with some different questions, for which you can get the answer revealed if you click on a button.

So that looks something like this:

[image]

Now, for each question I have I would like to know if the person reading it knows the answer to this question or not, by placing two icon above or below the box (have no decided yet). However, I am having a hard time to decide what icons are actually the best way of "asking" this. I've tried with thumbs up and down, but in some way, that seems more like a question about whether I like this question or not - not if I know the answer. The same goes for a checkmark and a cross. So which to icons would you recommend in a situation like this?

Comment: What happens when the user clicks that they know the answer? Do they enter it and have it checked by the system?

Comment: I was thinking that the answer is saved (for me to see at least), and then whatever icon they clicked is highlighted. So they are not redirected to anything else.

Comment: Do users receive any points or credit for correct answers? I.e. would you need to avoid them clicking "View Answer" and then adding that into the answer box?

Comment: Nope, it's all fun a giggles (for now at least). The idea behind the buttons is basically only for me, so I can get an idea of the difficulty on the questions. Maybe the icons could even disappear after clicked, with a thank you or something. I'm still not sure.

Comment: Voting to close this as too broad as it's an idea generating post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place a button next to the input box that says "Save answer" and use a checkmark on the button.

Below, you could use a link button that says "Show answer" and use an eye icon.

It sounds like, though, you want users to try to answer each question so that you can understand their difficulty, so you might want to not make the correct answer accessible until they make a guess and save it. You might want to eliminate the "Show answer" button altogether and just show the answer after the user saves their guess.

Comment: I actually like the eye icon idea. However, I do see a pitfall with your other suggestion. If the answer is first shown after they guess, they might have guessed wrong, and depending on what they clicked that might turn out to be wrong.

Comment: What is the pitfall with the user making the wrong guess, if the goal is to gauge whether or not they know the answer? What are the goals for the user, what are they trying to achieve?

Comment: Basically the idea is for me to get some data on the difficulty of each question. This approach will never get me 100% certainty - since they can just "cheat". So I know it will be an "in the ballpark" estimate - which is perfectly fine. So the interaction is purely for my benefit, and later on theirs. And that's why it has to be easy to understand, and simple to do so it doesn't require much from the user.

Comment: Then I stand by my answer that you should only display the correct answer after the user makes a guess.

Comment: Yes, after trying some things out, this is actually what I ended up with as well. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the icon, I would choose a design that keeps both within the same graphic style since they both refer to the same element, as happens with the like-unlike or check-uncheck buttons.

I come up with the brain of wisdom and question mark:

[image: brain head]
Those are the [Fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=head-side-brain) head-brain icons

Other classic symbols of knowledge are:

- book
- light bulb
- graduation hat
- owl

Search for some ideas at [thenounproject.com](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=knowledge).

Answer (score 1):

You basically already answered it yourself, but I would also go for the "checkmark/X" combination. The "Yes/No" you're asking about basically breaks down to a "worked/didn't work" or "success/failure" distinction, and the checkmark and X are well-known icons for that.

Also, since many other answers here kind of misinterpreted your aproach, let me clearly support your method here: While what you described may not be suitable for an actual test scenario, it is a very quick and easy way for simple and introductory training, so go for it. Of course it only works if the users are honest about their answers, so you should not base any kind of scoring or important rating on these answers alone. But to get started with learning new material (or something similar), it's a very painless method that works on pretty much any platform!